# Configure the Django development server (./manage.py runserver) to handle wildcard sub-domains?

Tags: django

Can you configure a Django development server to handle wildcard sub-domains?  I need to test any arbitrary sub-domain on my dev server and this is not possible by modifying the /etc/hosts/

The subdomain actually controls key behavior on the site (each user gets their own sub-domain and a user can have access to multiple sub-domains requiring non-trival testing on development.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the Django development server is not the problem. You will have to set up your DNS server to handle [wildcard records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) or add specific subdomains to your hosts file.

As I'm sure you're aware of, the Django dev server defaults to using `127.0.0.1:8000` but you can override this. If you override it with `localhost` it's likely handled by your `/etc/hosts` file and not by DNS. If you override it with something not in the /etc/hosts file, it is handled by DNS.

The easy case of adding specific subdomains in the `/etc/hosts` file, you've already covered in your question. Unfortunately you can't set up your hosts file to handle wildcard subdomains, for that you need to setup DNS ([OSX Snow Leopard instructions](http://geoffhankerson.com/node/108)).

Now — if you're okay with only testing through Firefox, you can solve the problem in a much easier way by using proxy autoconfiguration. See the [answers to this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684558/setting-up-wildcard-domains-on-local-host-os-x-10-5).

Comment: Running OSX.  Does DNS affect going to the localhost?  Please elaborate.

Comment: Extended my answer now, hope it helps!